# Finding the dimension of a subspace in $\mathbb R^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Given $S_{u}^\bot:=\{v\in \mathbb R^n:v \cdot u=0\}$, I've proved that $S_{u}^\bot$ is a subspace of $\mathbb R^n$. The next part of the question asks me to prove that $S_{u}^\bot$ has dimension of $n-1$.

I assume that it has something to do with the number of elements in the basis of the condition inside $S_{u}^\bot$ but do not know how to tackle. I also solved some other parts of the same question but I don't think that they're related to this part particularly.

Comment: One way is to show that $\mathbb{R}^n = \text{span}(u) \oplus S_u^\perp$.

Comment: Sorry, I'm pretty new to linear algebra and have not seen that symbol before. Would you mind giving me some context?

Comment: The symbol $\oplus$ means direct sum. If $U, W$ are subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$ then $\mathbb{R}^n = U \oplus W$ means that every vector $v$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ can be written uniquely as a sum $v = u + w$ for some $u \in U, w \in W$.

Comment: Sorry, I was just giving a suggestion. There might be a more direct/easier approach.

Comment: Just apply the rank nullity theorem to the functional which sends a vector to its dot product with u.

Comment: @Shalop Can you evaluate this? I'm not sure I understand even though I'm having the theory right in front of me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any vector $s \in V$, $s - (s \cdot u)u \in S_u^\perp$, by definition of $S_u^\perp$. In particular, $s = (s\cdot u)u + v$ for some $v \in S_u^\perp$.

This shows that every vector can be written as a linear combination of a vector in the span of $u$, and in $S_u^\perp$. In other words, $S_u^\perp + \overline{\{u\}}= V$.

However, as the subspaces are disjoint (why?) the sum is infact a direct sum, so by the usual relation between the dimensions of two vector spaces and that of their direct sum, one can conclude.

Comment: If $u$ is not a unit vector, then $s - (s \cdot u)u$ might not be in $S_u^\perp$ (depending on our definition of $S_u^\perp$). Now, I think I see what you mean, in the sense that in considering the orthogonal complement of a nonzero vector we can just use any nonzero vector in its span, including a normalized one. But the OP might not know this.

Comment: Would it help if I post the whole question? I was given a column vector $u \in \mathbb R^n$ and  a given matrix $H:=I_n = 2uu^T$

Comment: @sol If the answer works for you and you can follow through it then it should be fine. Otherwise you might just consider substituting the $(s \cdot u)u$ term with $(s \cdot \frac{u}{\lVert u \rVert}) \frac{u}{\lVert u \rVert}$.

Comment: @twosigma Yeah, I was also given that $||u||=1$ too! So it should work just fine I reckon

Comment: Ok, then there is no need to do what I've said. The answer is perfect.

Comment: Just saw all this, good to know it worked out!

Answer (score 1):

If you expand $v\cdot u=0$ in coordinates, you get a single homogeneous linear equation satisfied by the elements of $S_u^\perp$. Now apply the rank-nullity theorem to this system of one homogeneous equation.